# AI with complex board representation: simulating a single possible move

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

I am currently developing a turn-based grid-based strategy game (similar to Heroes of Might and Magic and Age of Wonders) using C#. Focusing on the combat part first.
There are multiple units on a grid, taking turns on attacking, shooting, casting spells, moving and so on.

Got a bit stuck on programming the AI. I want an AI that can plan ahead so I figured the process of finding the best action could be like this:

1. Generate list of possible moves
2. For each possible move:

   - Simulate move
   - Evaluate state

Then I repeat this process in a Minimax algorithm, somewhat similar to creating a chess AI.

The big difference from making a chess AI would be the "board representation" (or state); this game has a lot of complexity, and simply storing the state as an integer array would not suffice. There are multiple units with all kinds of fields, storing health, attack type, how they move and special abilities and so on….

So the problem I am facing is at the "simulating move" part. I need to make a function like `(previous state, move) => state`. I normally copy the previous state and perform the move on the copy. But I cannot find an efficient way of copying the state that the move will be performed on, seeing as it is very complex with lots of different objects. And the move should not alter the previous state.

What would be a good code structure to simulate a move without letting it affect the current board?

It could probably be done by just having an Undo() method for every move, but as logic grows complex it would be hard to keep track of everything that was changed.

I am after maybe some kind of software design pattern, or if somebody has done something similar I would like to know if they faced this problem.

A lot of questions on Stack Overflow talks about board game AI, but it always seems to be about chess/tic-tac-toe with easy board representations.

Comment: Usually, as in Chess, the AI system only looks ahead so many moves, it can't possibly calculate out every move (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number). This is probably what you should do, look ahead 10 turns, or 20, etc, depending on how complex you want the AI to be. This is one of many approaches though.

Comment: Ye, i was thinking of just looking ahead like 3 turns, when i was talking about moves i meant every possible action that the unit could perform during his turn

Comment: Consider scoping down your question - game AI design for whole game is way too broad for SO. You may also check out if http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour is better places for such question (also I suspect in current form it is too broad for any SE sites as it "requires a book to answer")

Comment: In general one does not evaluate all moves three down. One has an evaluation function and based on that one invest more effort in one move than in other moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem most *constraint programming solvers* deal with as well. In general these implement a hybrid between the `Command` and the `Memento` pattern. This works as follows:

You need a some **class that represents the state of the game** (here called `State`). Something that contains for instance the state of the board, the current player that can make a move, the resources every player has (if that's part of the game), etc. You better make such state a instance of [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): such that one can clone the state and do hypothetical processing on it.

So:

```
     ICloneable
          ^
          |
+-------------------+
|       State       |
+-------------------+
|+ Clone() : Object |
+-------------------+
```

Next you have a class `IMove` that represents possible moves on the state. The `IMove` can `Alter` the `State`. In most cases such method returns something as an `IAlterResult`: an object that stores some data for instance to undo the move.

```
+------------------------------+
|            IMove             |
+------------------------------+
|+ Alter(State) : IAlterResult |
+------------------------------+
```

and

```
+---------------------+
|    IAlterResult     |
+---------------------+
|+ Undo(State) : void |
+---------------------+
```

For instance if you remove a piece from the board, the `IAlterResult` stores where that piece stood, such that in case you undo the move, the `IAlterResult` can place the pawn (as an example), back on the board.

Each time you make a `IMove`, you push the corresponding `IAlterResult` on a `Stack<IAlterResult>`. This stack thus keeps track of the moves done, and can, by iteratively popping `IAlterResult`s and performing the `Undo` command bring the `State` back in the original state.

Most constraint programming solvers interleave copies of the `State` with `IAlterResults`. A stack thus looks like.

```
+---------------+
| AlterResult5  |
| AlterResult4  |
| Copy2         |
| AlterResult3  |
| AlterResult2  |
| AlterResult1  |
| Original copy |
+---------------+
```

In case you wish to backtrack four states, you can look first if there is a copy available, simply pop the first two alters (without `Undo`ing) then use the `Copy2` and undo the `AlterResult3` and `AlterResult2`. This can gain some efficiency if the Undo action requires heavy computational results.

You can also store the move you made in the `IAlterMove` in that case - if the move cannot be undone, or is hard to get undone - you can simply backtrack to the last preserved copy and perform all moves in the stack. So if you want for instance to undo the last move (`AlterResult5`) but that result cannot be undone, you can use `Copy2` and Redo the move stored in `AlterResult4`.

Comment: good answer, appreciate it.
Having to code Undo method for every move will require some effort, but this is the type of answer i was looking for

Comment: I assume the Clone method from State will recursively clone all fields it contains aswell?

Comment: @user1100931: yes. But the advantage is that you do the clone only once (or a few times) before going in AI mode. In general *undoing* a move will be more efficient than cloning since a move normally involves only a few pieces/players/...